# WooCommerce New Order Not Returning Billing E-Mail

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

i'm having a odd issue with WooCommerce.

I have a plugin I developed that sends data from WooCommerce orders to HubSpot. The plugin needs to fire *whenever a new order is placed OR an existing order is updated* . I've been using the following truncated code to try to achieve this:

```
add_action('save_post', 'printout', 10, 3);

function printout($post_ID, $post, $update)
{
    if ("shop_order" == $post->post_type) {
        $msg = $post_ID;

        delegator($msg);
    }
}

function delegator($order_id){

        $order = get_woocommerce_order($order_id);
            // assigns the actual data of the order to the $data variable
            $data = get_woocommerce_order_data($order);

            // assign User e-mail for search
            $email = $order->get_billing_email();

            //$email = get_post_meta( $order_id, '_billing_email', true );


}
```

The problem i'm having is that upon new Orders being made, WordPress can't get the order details, specifically a e-mail (it returns null). The hook *does* return an order number, so I don't think it's the hook doing this but something else.

The odd part is if after the order is placed and I go into the Order page and just hit **update** on the order, it works!

So I'm wondering what I'm missing / what's wrong here. Does the flow of the hook fire before WooCommerce can make database calls?

Thanks for any help. Been driving me mad!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For orders added/updated through admin, use the code below

```
add_action('save_post_shop_order', 'backend_delegator', 10, 3);
    
    function backend_delegator($post_id, $post, $update) {
    
        // Orders in backend only
        if (!is_admin())
            return;
    
        // Get an instance of the WC_Order
        $order = new WC_Order($post_id);
    
        //Fired when create a new order
        if (!$update) {
            $email = $order->get_billing_email();
        }
    
        if ($update) {
            $email = $order->get_billing_email();
        }
    }
```

For orders placed from checkout, use the code below.

```
add_action('woocommerce_new_order', 'frondend_delegator', 10, 2);

function frondend_delegator($order_id, $order) {

    $email = $order->get_billing_email();
}
```

Comment: So quick question. This atleast made e-mails work but order data still isn't retrieved by the $order info from the new order hook....any idea what causes that? It's odd because I can grab the user info from it but not actual order products etc.